# Customized Unity Event with a Parameter

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine

I have overridden Unity's zero-argument event class, so that I can return a `string` parameter when my customized event is invoked. This parameter is simply the code of the pressed key.

However, when I try to include the string-cast of the returned key code, I get an error message that the key code does not exist in the current context.

I am confused why it is not recognized and why I cannot return its string value with my event. Could someone please help me understand what I am doing wrong and how I can achieve my goal here?

In the first snippet below, the `"My event arg"` is of course returned with my event and printed to console, but when I replace it with `(String)kCode` or `kCode.ToString`, the `kCode` itself is not recognized...

```
public class EventScript : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Serializable]
    public class RadioEvent : UnityEvent<string> { }
    public RadioEvent OnRadioClicked = new RadioEvent();


    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.anyKeyDown)
        {
            foreach(KeyCode kCode in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)) )
            {
                if (Input.GetKeyDown(kCode) )
                    Debug.Log("KeyCode = " + kCode);
            }

            OnRadioClicked.Invoke("My event arg");
        }
    }
}


public class RadioManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private EventScript _eventScript;


    void Awake()
    {
        _eventScript = GetComponentInChildren<EventScript>();
    }


    void Start()
    {
        _eventScript.OnRadioClicked.AddListener(MyEventHandler);
    }


    void OnDestroy()
    {
        _eventScript.OnRadioClicked.RemoveListener(MyEventHandler);
    }


    void MyEventHandler(string name)
    {
        Debug.Log("My event handled with " + name);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a problem of scope and lifetime of a variable

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.anyKeyDown)
    {
        foreach(KeyCode kCode in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)) ) // kCode is created
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(kCode) )
                Debug.Log("KeyCode = " + kCode);
        } kCode is removed from stack
        kCode is no longer known to the compiler
        OnRadioClicked.Invoke("My event arg");
    }
}
```

See the { } define the lfi of a variable. In the case of your loop, whatever is created within the bracket lives between the closest opening brackt above and the matching closing bracket:

```
{
    var myVar = 1;
    { 
       var otherVar = 2;
    }
    myVar = 3; // this is ok but otherVar is no longer visible
}
myVar =  4; // Error
```

So if you want your kCode to live longer you need to declare it before the loop or call the event within the loop (better).

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.anyKeyDown)
    {
        foreach(KeyCode kCode in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KeyCode)) )
        {
            if (Input.GetKeyDown(kCode) ){
                Debug.Log("KeyCode = " + kCode);
                OnRadioClicked.Invoke(kCode.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation and help.